# PDFbox, exception on fonts

Tags: java, exception, fonts, pdfbox

I've write a simple code for edit content of a form inside a pdf. Everithing works fine (new pdf is created with modified form) but a strange excetpion about fonts were thrown. This is my code:

```
try {
        PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load("/home/giozh/universita/schedepazienti.pdf");
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

        PDField field = acroForm.getField("dx1");
        if (field != null) {
            field.setValue("asd");
        } else {
            System.err.println("No field found with name:" + "applicationPrepaid[0].#pageSet[0].Pagina1[0].txtFirstName[0]");
        }
        pdfDoc.save("/home/giozh/universita/schedepazienti1.pdf");
        pdfDoc.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Prove.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (COSVisitorException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Prove.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and this is exception:

```
Grave: error while creating a font
java.io.IOException: Cannot create font as /SubType is not set.
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:88)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFonts(PDResources.java:203)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAppearance.getFontAndUpdateResources(PDAppearance.java:439)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAppearance.setAppearanceValue(PDAppearance.java:268)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDVariableText.setValue(PDVariableText.java:131)
at prove.Prove.main(Prove.java:37)
```

(line 37 is where i call setValue() method)
how can i fix it?

Comment: The message seems to indicate that a font from the PDF is used which does not have a `/SubType` entry. Can you supply the PDF for inspection to verify?

Comment: the pdf is a pdf contains a picture, and only one form

Comment: this is the pdf file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxi2arJ2Dv9xcVpxd3ZOSDhXRUk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'll look at the PDF later (tomorrow in office). It seems to be somehow defect, though, at least Acrobat Reader wants to repair it.

Answer (score 1):

## In essence

Your PDF has an error which gracefully (merely with some logging output) is ignored.

## The details

The **AcroForm** dictionary in your PDF looks like this:

```
4 0 obj
<<
  /Fields [ 12 0 R ]
  /DA(/Helvetica 0 Tf 0 g )
  /DR
  <<
    /Font
    <<
      /Helvetica 11 0 R
      /Encoding<</PDFDocEncoding 10 0 R>>
    >>
  >>
  /NeedAppearances true
>>
endobj
```

The **Font** dictionary in there contains one entry for the font **Helvetica** (which is the font used in the field in question, cf. its **DA** value */Helvetica 0 Tf 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg*) and an entry for **Encoding** whose value does not represent a font at all.

PDFBox tries to parse that "font" called **Encoding** and fails doing so. but `PDResources.getFonts()` only logs the resulting exception and continues ignoring this issue:

```
try
{
    newFont = PDFontFactory.createFont( (COSDictionary)font );
}
catch (IOException exception)
{
    LOG.error("error while creating a font", exception);
}
```

> *(pdfbx-1.8.2.jar, org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources)*

Thus, you see the exception headed by "error while creating a font" (because it explicitly is logged like that) but the result is created all right (because the exception essentially is ignored).

Comment: so it's only a pdf problem and i can ignore it?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Yes, it is a problem of the PDF, not the code. But no, strictly speaking the source PDF is erroneous and you, therefore, should not use it as input but instead ask for a proper source file. Otherwise your output contains the same error and someone else who has to process your PDF stumbles over it just like you did. Maybe that person then even turns to you as producer of the erroneous file and asks you to repair it.

Comment: the file it's not created by me. So i'll try to fix it by myself

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that I was getting a similar issue for Helvetica font, which is a standard font It turned out to be the size of the form text area.  The form would fill, but when it went to flatten the fields would disappear.  I think this was a combination of issues (wrapping, overflow, etc), but the only error in the logs was about the font. The form was created using adobe, and filled with PDFbox